# Syntax error in bash

Tags: bash, unix

I want to write script in bash (I start programming in bash), but i have error, i try everything, and still i don't know how to repair this.

```
#!/bin/bash
cap=0
cat|while read line
  do
  read a
    if[$a -gt $cap]
       then echo "MORE"
fi
done
```

That's easy script, but i'm newbie in bash, please someone help me ;)

Comment: Explain what you are trying to accomplish with your script.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: First off, $line already contains the current line that was read from the input file, so you don't need the second read a or else you're going to miss half the lines of the input file.

Comment: Second you don't need the cat|, the while read will read from stdin without that.

Comment: There are many problems with this code.

Answer (score 8):

The syntax error is here:

```
if[$a -gt $cap]
```

You need whitespace, and quotes (to be safe with content with spaces or empty values):

```
if [ "$a" -gt "$cap" ]
```

Somewhat better would be to use the `[[` test mechanism, which is syntax (rather than `[`, which is a command), and doesn't need double quotes to be safe:

```
if [[ $a -gt $cap ]]
```

Even better than that would to be use a math context, which lets you use traditional mathematical operators and automatically dereferences variables:

```
if (( a > cap )) ; then ...
fi
```